# Android network thread and view/gui updates

Tags: android

I have a catch 22 here.  If I use a AsyncTask to run my network activity I can't update my user interface from that thread.

```
MainActivity.onCreate(...){
   myAsyncTask.execute();
   //E/AndroidRuntime(1177): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
}
```

The Network activity will be continuous and needs to happen on a different thread.  So, I turned to `super.runOnUiThread` to fix the error above and because it accepts `Runnable` as its parameter.  Unfortunatly, the Javadocs are not clear in that I don't know if `super.runOnUiThread` is going to make a Thread or just call `run` directly.  Apparently it does not make a Thread, because I get this exception: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Given that I have a one-screen App that need a connection.  What is the simplest way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use a AsyncTask to run my network activity I can't update my user interface from that thread

That is why `AsyncTask` has `onPostExecute()`. Put your UI update logic in there (or `onProgressUpdate()`, if you wish to update the UI as the background work is going on).

Comment: Thank you, but my network runnable object (inside of the AsyncTask) sends status calls back via an interface anytime it has to re-connect or is connected.  I don't see how it can do this, it does not even have a reference to the AsyncTask.  Are you saying I have to hack it to get these messages to all somehow fit through the Progress object?

Comment: @jcalfee314: `AsyncTask` is for transactional sorts of work. If you are trying to have a long-running thread, fork your own `Thread`. You can then use any number of means to have that background thread arrange to do work on the main application thread, such as the `runOnUiThread()` you referenced in your question. The key is that you cannot do network I/O on the main application thread. The `Runnable` you use with `runOnUiThread()` should *only* be arranging to update the UI *and do nothing else*. You already have a background thread/thread pool/whatever for the background work.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare said you can use onProgressUpdate() to update your UI .Here is an example, I used it to make a cool splash screen.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyz7112k4m1booh/1.png

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    bar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    new PrefetchData().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
    return true;
}


 private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // before making http calls         

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
         Random ran=new Random();
         int count;
         int total=0;
         try {
              while(total <= 100){
               count=ran.nextInt(30);
               total+=count;                 
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               if (total >= 100) publishProgress(""+100);
      //here publishProgress() will invoke onProgressUpdate() automatically .
                 else publishProgress(""+(int) total);
               }
             }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error:",e.getMessage());
            }
         return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            bar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);            
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }

    }
```